# Occuring error when i am running GWT in netbeans

Tags: gwt, ant, netbeans-7

undeploy-clean:
**C:\Users\ashfaque\Documents\NetBeansProjects\webapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1405: Problem:** 
failed to create task or type nbundeploy
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I would suspect a error in your ant file. Please provide exception stacktrace by running your ant build in debug mode.

Comment: Will you please elaborate this , i am new on this framework